# Nested-loop only providing last loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested-loops, enumerate

I have the following DataFrame:

```
    Activity    SMILES
0   1.0         CCN1CCCC1CNC(=O)c1cc([N+](=O)[O-])cc(O)c1OC
1   1.0         O=c1cc(-c2cccs2)oc2ccc(OCCCCCCN3CCC(O)CC3)cc12
2   1.0         CCCCCCCCCC(=O)N1c2ccc(Cl)cc2N=C(N2CCN(C)CC2)c2...
3   1.0         CCN1C(=O)c2ccccc2S(=O)c2ccc(C(=O)NCc3ccc4c(c3)...
4   1.0         CCN1CCc2cc(OCCF)cc3c2C1Cc1cccc(O)c1-3
    ...         ...
```

and I would like to get the following output:

```
    Activity    SMILES                                          cluster cluster set
0   1.0     CCN1CCCC1CNC(=O)c1cc([N+](=O)[O-])cc(O)c1OC         0.0     val
1   1.0     O=c1cc(-c2cccs2)oc2ccc(OCCCCCCN3CCC(O)CC3)cc12      898.0   test
2   1.0     CCCCCCCCCC(=O)N1c2ccc(Cl)cc2N=C(N2CCN(C)CC2)c2...   7.0     val
3   1.0     CCN1C(=O)c2ccccc2S(=O)c2ccc(C(=O)NCc3ccc4c(c3)...   4.0     train
5   1.0     FC(F)(F)c1cccc(N2CCN(Cc3cn(-c4ccccc4)c(-c4cccc...   856.0   val
    ...     ...                                                 ...     ...
```

I have three lists of tuples (train_points, test_points and val_points) which look like this:

```
[(4633, 0),
 (3935, 3907),
 (1410, 1409),
 (1120, 1121, 3, 3771),
 ...]
```

I have tried implementing the following loop sequence:

```
#Remove irrelevant information from the DataFrame
df_triplets = df[['Activity','SMILES']]

# Add clustering information
list_points = [train_points, test_points, val_points]
name_points = ['train','test','val']

# this loop should be working but it doesn't work
for name, points in zip(name_points,list_points):
    for num, cluster in enumerate(points):
        for molecule in cluster:
            df_triplets.loc[molecule,'cluster'] = num
            df_triplets.loc[molecule, 'cluster set'] = name
```

However, this only provides me df_triplets with the last cluster set (val_points) and not for the three sets that I am interested in. Please note that each 'molecule' is a unique number.